# getoutputmediafileuri method is not accessible?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-camera

I'm learning how to take a picture and save it's path into a file.

According to the tutorials offers on [android developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents), the method

`getoutputmediafileuri()` is used, however, when I tried to use that method, i found that it's

not accessible or undefined, i mean eclipse underlines this method with redline. I don't know

how to fix this error.

Please find below the code

```
public class SaveCameraImageDemoActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button btn01;
private Uri fileURI;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn01);
    btn01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intenet = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileURI = getoutputmediafileuri();
            //intenet.putExtra("output", uri.getPath());
            startActivityForResult(intenet,0);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no inbuilt method `getoutputmediafileuri()` in android.
It is a custom method someone write for getting file URI to store captured images in particular directory. You have to defined and put logic for it. Instead of that use this code,

**EDIT:**

```
btn01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
       imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
       File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
       Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
       imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
       startActivityForResult(imageIntent,0);
  }
});
```

Now this will store your camera captured images in **MyImages** directory in sdcard with **image_001.jpg** name.

Comment: How to find the Android default image storage path?

Answer (score 11):

The getoutputmediafileuri() method is defined here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

Answer (score 2):

Now [the document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) has added the code. Just paste the at the end of your `Class`, it work well for me. Code See As Below.

```
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
  return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new   File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: can you show me please an example how to add the above code in intent?